# How to make a charts using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, charts

Iam really new in to jQuery or something.
Iam using adminlte2 template as my project dashboards, and i use codeigniter as my framework.
I want to use charts based on this.

```
$(function () {
  var donutData = [
  {label: "Series1", data: 30, color: "#1a5dad"},
  {label: "Series2", data: 20, color: "#2b6cbc"},
  {label: "Series3", data: 50, color: "#3c7bcb"},
  {label: "Series4", data: 50, color: "#4d8ada"}
];
$.plot("#donut-chart", donutData, {
  series: {
    pie: {
      show: true,
      radius: 1,
      innerRadius: 0.5,
      label: {
        show: true,
        radius: 2 / 3,
        formatter: labelFormatter,
        threshold: 0.1
      }

    }
  },
  legend: {
    show: false
  }
});
/*
 * END DONUT CHART
 */
```

The task is just, how to change label and data in that code into variable?
I already have the variable for label: $row['productSubgroup'] and for data: $row['counts']. And i just cant input it... Hope someone will help.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your situation your code will be like this:

**Controller :**

```
$chart_data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $chart_data[] = array(
                                    'label' => $row['productSubgroup'],
                                    'data'  => $row['count'],
                                    'color' => dechex(rand(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF)) //Random Hex color code
                                );
}
$data['chart_data'] = json_encode($chart_data);
```

Explanation : This code will get label and count from your data store. `$result` is having your data. We're preparing array for chart and storing it in `$data['chart_data']`, it is in json format. You've to pass $data to the view file.

**JS :**

```
$(function () {
    var donutData = <?php echo $chart_data; ?>;
    $.plot("#donut-chart", donutData, {
      series: {
        pie: {
          show: true,
          radius: 1,
          innerRadius: 0.5,
          label: {
            show: true,
            radius: 2 / 3,
            formatter: labelFormatter,
            threshold: 0.1
          }

        }
      },
      legend: {
        show: false
      }
    });
/*
 * END DONUT CHART
 */
});
```

Explanation : `$chart_data` holds the chart details. We're storing this php variable data into `donutData`.

Try this and let me know if there is any issue.

**Happy Coding!**